# Webpack cannot find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new on webpack and I'd like to use third party react component in my project. I installed the componet that i need and the dir `node_modules` was created and my project's tree look like:

```
reactcalendar
  |--node_modules
  |   |--.bin
  |   |--babel-cli
  |   |--babel-core
  |   |--babel-preset-es2015
  |   |--babel-preset-react
  |   |--babelify
  |   |--file-loader
  |   |--moment
  |   |--react
  |   |--react-big-calendar (the third party component)
  |   |--react-dom
  |   |--webpack
  |--.babelrc
  |--bundle.js (empty)
  |--index.html
  |--index.js
  |--package.json
  |--webpack.config.js
```

Some file was used for browserify but it gave me the same error...

My **index.html** look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Calendar</title>
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My **index.js** look like this:

```
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);

ReactDOM.render(<BigCalendar
    events={myEventsList}
    startAccessor='startDate'
    endAccessor='endDate'
/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

And my `webpack.config.js` look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,

    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ["babel-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]",
            }
        ]
    },

    entry: {
        javascript: "./index.js",
        html: "./index.html"
    }
}
```

When i run the command `webpack` into my root project it gave me this error:

```
C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar>webpack
Hash: ebfe4ff0eeeaed3060c6
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 12753ms
     Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.html  231 bytes          [emitted]
 bundle.js     469 kB    0, 1  [emitted]  html, javascript
    + 105 hidden modules

ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-big-calendar' in C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar
 @ ./index.js 3:24-53
```

Maybe I'm wrong with the config file of webpack?

Comment: can you provide repo?

Comment: check into the react-big-calendar module and see if that module is exported as default or not. if not than you have to import as `import * as BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar'`. Maybe it works

Comment: @Utro Do you mean the repo of the third party react component? if yes: https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar.git

Comment: i mean this project, in order to test

Comment: @Utro this is the [link](https://mega.nz/#!NAgxTa6Y)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i tried it but doesn't work, i think is exported as default because i paste the code inside index.js from the documentation of the component

Comment: @Utro sorry this is the right [link](https://mega.nz/#!NAgxTa6Y!gReeVwmK0En5cPyYKtVUNgeTnpURMWSPLHOLXNTP6zA)

Comment: :D  it will take a time to unzip )))

Comment: i tried to upload the unzip folder but it freeze my browser :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.delete node_modules folder.

2.then `npm install`

3.Change your code in index.js to this

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

BigCalendar.setLocalizer(BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment));
const myEventsList = [{'event':'test2'},{'event':'test1'},{'event':'test3'}]

render(<BigCalendar
    events={myEventsList}
    startAccessor='startDate'
    endAccessor='endDate'
/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

4.in index.html you should put bundle.js into body

```
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do I have to reinstall other modules such as `babel-core, babel-preset-es2015, {...}` or just `react-big-calendar`?

Comment: when you deleted node_modules folder, you have to reinstall all mudules, through ```npm install ``` in console

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using React, but my problem was solved by setting the `module` field in `tsconfig.json` from `UMD` to `AMD`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "AMD",
    "target": "ES5",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```